# JavaScript Jasmine: trigger keydown event

Tags: jasmine

I'm trying to test the keydown event on a text box to determine if a character supplied, is valid or not, but this is turning out to be an impossible task.

I have a selector, like such:

```
$('<input type="text" id="rwSearchText" />').appendBody('body');
```

I have a function then that defines the check for the valid keys:

```
var addKeyDownEvent = function() {

    $('#rwSearchText').keydown(function(event) {

        var keyCode = event.which;

        if ((keyCode > 64 && keyCode < 91) || keyCode === 189 || keyCode === 222 || keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE
            || keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.DELETE || keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.SPACE
            || keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.LEFT || keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.RIGHT
            || keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.SHIFT || keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.END
            || keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.HOME) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    });

};
```

I call this, in the beforeEach() method along with the appendTo('body') to create the textbox I need to test against:

```
beforeEach(function ()
{
    rwSearchText = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"#rwSearchText\" />").appendTo("body");
    addKeyDownEvent();
});
```

rwSearchText is defined globally.

then in my define -> it('@ should not be allowed', function() {}); I'm triggering the keydown manually:

```
describe("rwSearchText", function() {

    it("single dash should be allowed", function() {

        rwSearchText.val('&');
        rwSearchText.trigger('keydown');

        var results = rwSearchText.val();

    });

});
```

but the keydown event is never fired.

Is there something I'm missing? I've Googled similar scenarios but what I've done seems correct. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: In you test - are appending HTML?

Comment: I am, from the code example given, in the beforeEach() function

Comment: Maybe the solution will be split test to two test - if some key is presses is attached listener fired and test for attached listener - without HTML.
It is not working as you have put some value to input then call keydown - your methods has nothing to do with keydown - the value is already set.